# How to implement `EQ` of LISP in lambda calculus?

Tags: lisp, lambda-calculus

I'm learning lambda calculus these days and found it very beautiful and interesting, but I haven't found out how to implement the `EQ` primitive of LISP, which judges if two symbols are the same.

I have found many materials for implementing integer arithmetic (using Church Numbers) and boolean logic, but failed to find a solution for `EQ`. I hope `EQ` works like this(the same of LISP):

```
(EQ x x) --> True
(EQ x y) --> False
(EQ (x y) (x y)) --> False // return true only for simple symbols, not structures
```

Any help.

---

**Update:**

I do not mind to wrap symbols into some contexts, for example:

```
(EQ (lambda u . u symbol x) (lambda u . u symbol x)) --> True
(EQ (lambda u . u symbol x) (lambda u . u symbol y)) --> False
```

---

**I've found a possible solution:**

If we restrict symbols in a finite set, e.g., `Symbols = {A, B, C}`, then we can define an `EQ` like this:

```
A = λ A B C. A
B = λ A B C. B
C = λ A B C. C
EQ = λ x y. ChurchEQ (x 1 2 3) (y 1 2 3)    // Here 1, 2, 3 should be replaced by Church Numbers
```

I have tested these code in an interpreter, and it works.

**But one problem remains:** The `EQ` itself can't be placed into `Symbols`.

Comment: then what would `((lambda symbol. symbol) 1)` evaluate to?

Comment: and what ***should*** `EQ (λu.ux) (λu.uy)` **inside** `(λy.(λx.EQ (λu.ux) (λu.uy)) y)` evaluate to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to define a *general* notion of equality for arbitrary terms in the lambda calculus. Depending on the implementation `EQ` is either defined as syntactic equality (perhaps up to α-equivalence) or pointer equality which have to be defined in the implementation of your interpreter and not in the language itself.

That said, there are many cases of *specific* lambda expressions ( i.e. church numerals, church booleans ) where there is a well-defined decision procedure for determining equality which of course be encoded in the lambda calculus, just like it can be encoded in any language. For example for booleans:

```
T = λ x y. x
F = λ x y. y
not = λ p. p F T
xor = λ p q. p (q F T) q
equ = λ p q. not (xor p q)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know these booleans work, but how about `EQ`? I do not mind wrapping symbols in some context, e.g. `EQ (symbol x) (symbol x)`.

Comment: @SaltyEgg There's no *symbols* in  LC itself, by definition, it only deals with *values*. You can not define the notions of "free" and "bound" variables in lambda calculus itself, either. It's all a part of how you *implement* it in the computer, or in your head when working with pencil and paper.

Comment: @WillNess Theoretically speaking, I can implement a LISP using LC, but I don't know how, especially `EQ`. I found examples for testing equality of Church numbers, but I don't know how to transfer symbols (or strings) to Church numbers.

Comment: @SaltyEgg it's the other way around; you implement LC in LISP. EQ as part of LISP is non-reducible to LC. There's no EQ in LC because EQ is pointer-equality and there's no pointers in LC.

Comment: @SaltyEgg ``EQ`` can only be an implementation detail of the interpreter itself. There is no way to introspect syntax from within the pure lambda calculus.

Comment: @freyrs According to my understanding, lambda calculus can do what a Turing machine does. where did I go wrong?

Comment: @SaltyEgg Ask yourself how you would define ``eq`` in terms of Turing machines, it's just as meaningless to ask. I don't know what you're thinking, but my guess is you've misunderstood some existence proof you've heard about the calculable equivalence of the *abstract* Turing machines and *abstract* LC and are trying to apply this assumed property to a concrete implementation on stock hardware and it's leading you to wrong assumptions about what you can and can't write in the LC.

Comment: @freyrs I have found one possible solution, see my updated question.